# my code results 0 when i attempt to enter input

Tags: c++, eclipse

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : Lab02.cpp
// Author      : Insert name
// Version     :
// Copyright   : 
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================
/*
 * Write a program that displays
 * First and last name on one line
 * Address on the nest line
 * writes your city, state, zip on next line
 * writes telephone number on the next line
 *
 * Example: First Last
 *          123 Street Avenue
 *          City, Ca. Zipcode
 *          (925)555-5555
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    long double fullName;
    unsigned int address;
    string cityZip;
    unsigned int phoneNumber;

    cout << "Please enter you full name" << endl;
    cin >> fullName;
    cout << fullName << endl;

    cout << "Enter your address" << endl;
    cin >> address;
    cout << address << endl;

    cout << "Please enter your city, zipzode, and state" << endl;
    cin >> cityZip;
    cout << cityZip << endl;

    cout << "Enter your phone number" << endl;
    cin >> phoneNumber;
    cout << phoneNumber << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

**This is the console output**

```
Please enter you full name
first last
0
Enter your address
0
Please enter your city, zipzode, and state

Enter your phone number
0
```

**My code keeps outputting 0's and doesnt let me finish enter what the code prompts. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Should i use GetLine instead of string?**

Comment: Why is your full name a `long double`? And your address a `unsigned int`?

Comment: @tkausl I was attempting to see what was causing the problem. Should i not be using them?

Answer (score 2):

```
long double fullName;

cout << "Please enter you full name" << endl;
cin >> fullName;
```

A `long double` is a numeric value. You are prompting for input into a numeric value. You can try very hard to enter a name, here, but since the value is a `long double`, it obviously is not going to work.

The input parsing failure is going to put `std::cin` into a failed state, and all subsequent input operations will immediately fail, resulting in the ouput you have observed.

In conclusion:

1. Fix the type of all your variables. They should be `std::string`s.
2. Use `std::getline()` to enter a line of text. `operator>>` parses a single whitespace-delimited work. Your intent here, with every prompt, is to read an entire line of text, possibly containing spaces. `operator>>` will stop reading at the first space.

Comment: So after using the std::getline(std::cin,fullName);
The console prints the full name yet it still returns 0 and wont let me finish inputting for the rest of the prompts?

Comment: It's not just `fullName`. Same thing with all the other variables.

Comment: So change it the variables to string and do this 
 cout << "Please enter you full name" << endl;
 std::getline(std::cin,fullName);
 cout << fullName << endl;

 cout << "Enter your address" << endl;
 std::getline(std::cin,address);
 cout << address << endl;

 cout << "Please enter your city, zipzode, and state" << endl;
 std::getline(std::cin,cityZip);
 cout << cityZip << endl;

 cout << "Enter your phone number" << endl;
 std::getline(std::cin,phoneNumber);
 cout << phoneNumber << endl;